# Umbraco: how can i get a node by property value with uQuery?

Tags: xpath, umbraco

Maybe someone can help, is it a way to combine an xPath expression to query node by it's property value?

I have a node with custom property "ItemId". I need something like this:

```
uQuery.GetNodesByXPath("//* [@itemId = '<someId>']")
```

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"`//*`" Will give you all nodes, so "`//*[@itemId = '<someId>']`" is asking to give you all nodes with an attribute equal to exactly "`<someId>`", which you can't have as a valid attribute.

So, if you have `<myNode someId='my Id value'></myNode>` , then try `//*[@itemId='someId']`
But remember, this will give you ANY node with that particular attribute ID.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but please post your XML or a snippet of what you're grabbing, as that will clear up any grey areas.